# AMP validation error: The attribute 'cite' may not appear in tag 'q'

Tags: amp-html

When validating a URL with `#development=1` I get the following error:
**The attribute 'cite' may not appear in tag 'q'.**

the tag in question is used like this: `<q cite="URL">lorem ipsum</q>`.

I couldn't find anything about this issue in the docs, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten the following response on github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues

> This tag/attr pair is actually allowed in the latest version, but it
>   may be a week or two before we can roll it out everywhere. In the
>   meantime, I'm letting the developer console errors continue to show it
>   to avoid confusion. If you want to ignore these messages your pages
>   will soon validate, just not quite yet.

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/2590

Answer (score 1):

The `cite` attribute for `<q>` tags is now allowed in AMP.